# CSS classes, order of precedence

Tags: css, class, operator-precedence

I stumbled on CSS issue I don't understand. 
I have a parent class with some styles on element, and a class on the element itself which, in my opinion, should overwrite parent class, but it doesn't:

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>Regular Paragraph</p>
    <p class="note">Note paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.note {
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

I don't like to use ids instead of classes, and I don't like to have important! anywhere in my styles. I understand that I can use "div" instead of "p" to fix the problem in this case. But I try to figure out why the precedence works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the element along with the class will give the selector priority over the parent definition. Try setting `p.note {` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zfoqtd4/

Comment: Probably because it's wrong. Element selectors don't have priority. Far from it.

Comment: Ok, I've rephrased that

Comment: It's still wrong, I'm afraid. In your jsfiddle, the `p.note` rule beats the `.parent p` rule only because it comes after. Try reversing the two rules to see. And the last rule wins only because the two selectors have the same specificity. (which is 0,0,1,1)

Comment: Weird. I tried p.note declaration in my example, it didn't work. But in your example it works somehow. I guess there was some typo or something in my code? In any case, if the issue can be solved this way, it is not an issue anymore. thanks

Comment: Alohci, you are right, in this case the order of declaration is important. I will have to have it in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use

```
.parent .note {

}
```

to apply your styling.

Comment: In this case I will have to add a specific entry for every parent class, which is not helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. However this means that the .note class will exist only inside .parent and functions just like a normal class just in a different scope. Ultimately, `!important` is designed to choose which rule overwrites another rule. In other words, you should not think of `!important` as a dirty trick or something if you would happen to think that.

Comment: I do happen to think that :)
But, of course, not as dirty as rewriting a class rule for every parent->class combination.

Comment: @olka_sb - If you want all elements with class "note" to take priority over `.parent p` rules, you can increase the specificity of the `.note` rule by repeating the class name. So `.note.note` (specificity 0,0,2,0) beats `.parent p` (specificity 0,0,1,1).

Comment: But it is a dirty hack though :)